# how to do a echo function to a file's last word in python

Tags: python, string

The detailed question is :
Write a function that takes a single string representing a filename as an argument and a number, x.
Open the file and use a while loop to build and return a string containing the phrase from the file 
and the last word x times. 
Note the new lines.

```
def echo(filename, x):
    """
    >>> echo("phrase.txt", 2)
    'Hello World!\\nWorld!\\nWorld!\\n'
    >>> echo("phrase.txt", 4)
    'Hello World!\\nWorld!\\nWorld!\\nWorld!\\nWorld!\\n'
    """

if __name__=="__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

what Im trying to do is:

```
def echo(filename,x):
    files=open(filename,"r")
    text=files.read()
    filelist=text.split()
    last_word=filelist[len(filelist)-1]
    n=len(last_word)
    count=last_word
    while n<n*x:
        count=count+last_word
        n=n+1
    return count
```

but unfortunately, this is not gonna work.
as a new fish who still struggling in python, I really need somebody to give me a hand.

Comment: Btw, the whole content of phrase.txt is only one sentence "Hello World!"

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. I'm going to make minimal changes to your code, adding comments anywhere I make changes:

```
def echo(filename,x):
    files = open(filename,"r")
    text = files.read()
    filelist = text.split()
    last_word = filelist[len(filelist)-1]
    n = 1  # let's just count the number of times you add the last word
    count = text
    while n<x:
        count = count + last_word
        n = n + 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answerer isn't quite right... This is how it should be :)

```
def echo(filename, x):
    files = open(filename,"r")
    text = files.read()
    filelist = text.split()
    last_word = text.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
    files.close()
    n = 0
    string = text
    while n < x:
        string = string + "\n" + last_word
        n = n + 1
    return string + "\n"
```